# Use a query to sort a report in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, sorting, report

I am a beginner in MS Access and am currently stuck with a problem.
I have a database about movies and I'm currently creating a list of all the movies that I want to have sorted by popularity.
To determine the popularity of a movie I have a different table that has a history of what my customers have watched, every movie they have watched is a seperate entry in that table.

I have created a report that has 3 things, the title of the movie, the ID of the movie and a button to watch that movie. But I want to sort the report to show the movies with the most viewers first.

I have created this code in SQL Management Studio which works exactly like I want too:

```
SELECT [Film].[Titel], [Film].[Film_ID], COUNT([historie].[Film_ID]) as timesWatched
FROM [Film] INNER JOIN [historie] on [Film].[Film_ID] = [historie].[Film_ID]
GROUP BY [Film].[Titel], [Film].[Film_ID]
ORDER BY timesWatched DESC
```

I'm not that good with Access yet and have no idea how I can use this query to sort the report, I tried putting it in the row source (with everything on one line) in the report properties, which didn't work.

I hope someone has an idea on what to do, is it possible to use this query somewhere or should I use something else than a Report?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: why you are saying **it did't work**. Explain that

Comment: I'm not that good with Access, so I don't know why it didn't work. I'll take a look at it again this afternoon and will report back when I find out. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong..

First create the Query in ACCESS (Create tab -> query) There you will be able to create that query, save it, then go to your report and set its source to this query, the last step will be to set each textbox/label source to the query field, I mean if you have a textField in your report where you want to diplay "movieName", you must select data source from this text box and choose between all fields in your query (in this case, and following a good practice, let's say the field is called movieName too).

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry for my late answer, didn't have access to my PC. I'm gonna try what you said in the afternoon and will report back. Thanks for the answer!